# Create, Modify, and Save an image in python 3.x

Tags: python, image, file, python-3.x, save

I'm currently making a program that renders information to a buffer, and I want to save the information as an image file of some sort to my working directory. I've seen some examples using PIL, but that library isn't supported for python 3.x. Are there better alternatives?

Comment: Try PIL's clone, [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow). It has a 3.X branch, last I checked.

Comment: Yep, Kevin is right.  I use Pillow for all my image manipulation needs in 3.x

Comment: Strange, I installed pillow via pip but I can't import it in the python command line. pip list shows that Pillow is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First uninstall PIL than install [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow)

its a PIL's clone which works on python 3.x.

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("test1.jpg") #jpg, png, etc.
pix = img.load()
print img.size #Get the width and height of the image for iterating over
print pix[15,15] #Get the RGBA Value of the a pixel of an image
pix[15, 15] = value # Set the RGBA Value of the image (tuple)
img.save("out.jpg") # Saves the modified pixels to image
```

Comment: I never had PIL installed in the first place, since I'm running python 3 and it's not listed in pip.

Comment: I attempted `pip uninstall pillow` and then `pip install pillow`, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: try downloading it manually and then install. `python setup.py install`

Comment: after uninstalling it from pip and reinstalling using easy_install, it seems to be working.